# Insert data in MS Access 2013 through groovy

Tags: ms-access, groovy, database-connection, driver

I want to insert a row in MS Access database using Groovy. I don't know what are the drivers needed and where they can be downloaded from. I am using Groovy 2.4.7 and MS Access 2013. Please tell me what has to be done clearly as I am new to Groovy. Any code would be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You just need a JDBC driver that works with MS Access (same as if you were using Java).

One candidate (open source LGPL or Apache licensed):
http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

The Groovy docs provide examples of how to use SQL:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html